# Create Ranking based on Dates(Annual) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

We will start with the following DataTable:

```
    id       date
 1:  1 2015-12-31
 2:  1 2014-12-31
 3:  1 2013-12-31
 4:  1 2012-12-31
 5:  1 2011-12-31
 6:  2 2015-12-31
 7:  2 2014-12-31
 8:  2 2014-01-25
 9:  2 2013-01-25
10:  2 2012-01-25

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 as.IDate(c("2015-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2013-12-31", "2012-12-31", 
                            "2011-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2014-01-25",
                            "2013-01-25", "2012-01-25")))
setnames(DT, c("id", "date"))
```

For every unique id, I want to create a ranking. The most current date for a specific id should have a rank of 0. After I should remove one year from that date to get the ranking -1. If the month is not the same as the date of rank 0, we should stop the ranking. For example, at the line 8, for the id=2, since the month is not december we should stop the ranking.

We would get the following result:

```
    id       date rank_year
 1:  1 2015-12-31         0
 2:  1 2014-12-31        -1
 3:  1 2013-12-31        -2
 4:  1 2012-12-31        -3
 5:  1 2011-12-31        -4
 6:  2 2015-12-31         0
 7:  2 2014-12-31        -1
 8:  2 2014-01-25        NA
 9:  2 2013-01-25        NA
10:  2 2012-01-25        NA
```

I have the following code so far (given by @Frank and @akrun) :

```
DT <- DT[order(id, -date)]
DT <- DT[,rank_year := { z = month(date) + year(date)*12
                         as.integer( (z - z[1L])/12) # 12 months
                       }, by = id]

    id       date rank_year
 1:  1 2015-12-31         0
 2:  1 2014-12-31        -1
 3:  1 2013-12-31        -2
 4:  1 2012-12-31        -3
 5:  1 2011-12-31        -4
 6:  2 2015-12-31         0
 7:  2 2014-12-31        -1
 8:  2 2014-01-25        -1
 9:  2 2013-01-25        -2
10:  2 2012-01-25        -3
```

Comment: Fyi, you should not `<-` a data.table when simply modifying columns or reordering. Have a look at the package vignettes, which will explain how these operations can be done by reference and the advantages of doing it this way https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: At first, I tried without `<-` but my table doesn't update and when I run the code after it doesn't work like I would like

Comment: The correct way to reorder is with `setorder`. The "by reference" functions are `:=` and a bunch with names like `set*`.

Comment: I will definitely look at the document. I am new to data.table but it is so much faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I guess I would do it like

```
DT[, rank_year := replace(
    year(date) - year(date)[1L],  
    month(date) != month(date[1L]), 
    NA_integer_
), by=id]

    id       date rank_year
 1:  1 2015-12-31         0
 2:  1 2014-12-31        -1
 3:  1 2013-12-31        -2
 4:  1 2012-12-31        -3
 5:  1 2011-12-31        -4
 6:  2 2015-12-31         0
 7:  2 2014-12-31        -1
 8:  2 2014-01-25        NA
 9:  2 2013-01-25        NA
10:  2 2012-01-25        NA
```

See `?replace` for details on how this works.

---

One way of extending the old answer is

```
DT[, r := {
   z = month(date) + year(date)*12
   res = (z - z[1L])/12
   as.integer( replace(res, res %% 1 != 0, NA) ) 
}, by=id]
```

Comment: and the obligatory `ifelse`: `DT[, rank := ifelse(month(date) != month(date[1L]), NA_integer_, year(date) - year(date)[1L]), by = id]`